# The C program crashes while executing function

Tags: c, arrays

Hello I have a problem when I call to function `arrayBigToSmall` the program crashes (after I enter the numbers).  I want to understand why this happens and how I can fix this problem.?

Code -

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
    float array[2][3][2];
    getNums(array);
    return(0);
    }

    void getNums(float array[2][3][2])
    {
    int i,j,p;

    printf("Enter numbers: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < 2 ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            for(p = 0; p < 2; p++)
            {
                scanf("%f",&array[i][j][p]);
            }
        }
    }
    arrayBigToSmall(array);
    }

    void arrayBigToSmall(float array[2][3][2])
    {

    int i,j,p,k;
    float array1[12];
    float temp;

    for( i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for( j=0; j  < 2; j++)
        {
            for(p = 0; p < 3; p++)
            {
                array1[k] = array[i][j][p];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: you failed to initialize `k` in `arrayBigToSmall()`. Your compiler would have told you if you compiled with all warnings enabled.

Answer (score 4):

```
for( i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    for( j=0; j  < 2; j++)
    {
        for(p = 0; p < 3; p++)
        {
            array1[k] = array[i][j][p];
            k++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

`k` must be initialized to `0`. `i` should be not greater than `2`, `j` not greater that `3`, and `p` not greater than `2`

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with size of array use following:
as the dimension of your array is `2 x 3 x 2` but in your code you are using 3 loops in `3 x 2 x 3` manner which overflows and which result in crash . 
Also you should intialise `k` before using it.

```
void arrayBigToSmall(float array[2][3][2])
{

int i,j,p,k=0;
float array1[12];
float temp;

for( i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    for( j=0; j  < 3; j++)
    {
        for(p = 0; p <2 ; p++)
        {
            array1[k] = array[i][j][p];
            k++;
        }
    }
}
}
```